HDMI media displaying upside down?
I have an outdoor advertising screen which has Android OS.
The Android OS all displays in the correct orientation, however, when i play any content through the HDMI, through the OS, it displays upside down?
Note: I can flip the Android OS in settings but i don't want to flip this, i just need HDMI content to play in same orientation.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Likely it has some setting for upside down projectors. Check that and adjust accordingly.
